# Which one sounds the most idiomatic: "during work", "during my work", "during my work day", "during my working hours"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Which one sounds the most idiomatic: *during work*, *during my work*, *during my work day*, *during my working hours*? For example:

> I drink quite a few cups of coffee **during work**.
>
> I drink quite a few cups of coffee **during my work**.
>
> I drink quite a few cups of coffee **during my work day**.
>
> I drink quite a few cups of coffee **during my working hours work**.

What I am trying to say is that while I am at work I drink quite a few cups of coffee.

If none of my sentences sounds natural, then what would a native English speaker say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following all sound just fine, though they have slightly different nuances:

> I drink quite a few cups of coffee during work.
>
> I drink quite a few cups of coffee during my work.
>
> I drink quite a few cups of coffee during my work day.

The following is *not* idiomatic, and is actually not even correct grammar:

> I drink quite a few cups of coffee during my working hours work. *(wrong)*

("during my working hours" would be fine, but the extra "work" on the end is not right)

Regarding the first three, they all express more or less the same thing, but with slightly different emphasis:

> I drink quite a few cups of coffee during work.

This basically says you drink a lot of coffee when you are working, or at your job.

> I drink quite a few cups of coffee during my work.

This says more or less the same thing, but the addition of "my" makes it seem more personal and about your specific work.  You might be implying that you drink more coffee because of your work than somebody else might drink because they have a different job, etc.

> I drink quite a few cups of coffee during my work day.

This says that you drink a lot of coffee during the day when you're at your job, but it's more about the natural course of your day, and not as much about the fact that you're working hard, etc.

Also, "work" and "work day" are generally taken to mean someone's job/employment, whereas "my work" could potentially refer to either that, or also something you work on outside of your main source of employment (such as a strenuous hobby, or a side-enterprise).

All of these differences are small, though, and really any of them could be used in most situations.